# julia: display the `catch` error in control flow

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, julia

Consider the following `try`/`catch` flow

```
function test(x)
    try x^3
        if x < 0; error("i only accept x >= 0"); end
        return x^3
    catch
        return abs(x)^3
    end
end
```

How can I display the error message (and stack trace) in the case `test(-2) # == 8`? In this case I know the error, but if it's a more complicated function with asserts etc, I'd like to know what specifically failed.

Trying `rethrow()` needs to be done in the try-catch block, but I still want a return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the `Exception` into a variable after writing the variable name of your choice right after `catch`. `error` creates an `ErrorException`. You can see the fields of this `Exception` using `fieldnames(ErrorException)`. The `msg` field gives you the message you passed to `error`. Alternatively, you may use `showerror` method.

```
function test(x)
    try x^3
        if x < 0; error("i only accept x >= 0"); end
        return x^3
    catch e
        showerror(stdout, e)
        # or 
        println(e.msg)
    end
end
```

For the stack trace, you may use `stacktrace(catch_backtrace())`. We pass [`catch_backtrace`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.catch_backtrace) to [`stacktrace`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/stacktraces/), because what we usually want is to obtain the stack trace of the context of the most recent exception and not the current context.

Comment: Thanks! What's the best way to include  `stacktrace(catch_backtrace())` in my function?

Comment: @jjjjjj If what you want is to display the stack trace, just add `display(stacktrace(catch_backtrace()))` before returning `abs(x)^3`.